# Reference an item by an identifier or a URL

Tags: schema.org, microdata

We started to use the vocabulary from Schema.org and we are looking for a simple and effective way to reference an object by its identifier or a unique URL.

For example, in the [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) type there is a property `employee` which refers to [`Person`](http://schema.org/Person). We would like to be able to refer to it using a unique identifier instead of the whole object.

What would be the best solution according to [Schema.org](http://schema.org)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Person` (resp. the name-value pairs) is defined on the same page, you could use the [`itemref` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#attr-itemref), containing reference to the `id`(s):

> Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemref` attribute specified, to give a list of additional elements to crawl to find the name-value pairs of the item.

---

With [Microdata’s `itemid` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27548930/1591669) you can specify a URL that identifies an item.

However, Microdata requires that vocabularies explicitly specify support of `itemid`, which Schema.org [hasn’t done yet](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/76).