# Is it okay to use same schema.org markup twice on one page?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, structured-data

On a product page I have two aggregated ratings for one product at different places, which means they contain identical information. I want to have them twice on that page due to ux reasons, but I'm not sure if I can markup them with schema.org everytime or if this would be a useless duplication.

Wondered if there is a solution with `itemref` but in my opinion it's not helpful for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use `itemid`, consumers can’t be sure that two (or more) items are (about) the same thing. So they would learn that your `Product` item has *two* `AggregateRating` items. Consumers *might* try to deduce that both items should be the same (e.g., by comparing `url` values), but you would better not rely on this.

So you should use the [`itemid` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27548930/1591669) (Schema.org does not yet claim to support it, which Microdata requires, but [according to this issue](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/76), it’s intended to document it sometime), giving both of your `AggregateRating` items the same URI.

But consumers don’t necessarily support `itemid`, so they might still have problems guessing that these items are about the same thing.

So ideally: markup only one occurence (per document) with Schema.org.