# How to split itemscope over multiple HTML elements?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I have the following HTML:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    <nav itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    </nav>
    ...
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemref="objectDetails">
      <span itemprop="name">Org name</span><br>
      <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        ...
      </span>
    </div>
  </header>
  <ul itemprop="breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">..</li>
    ...
  </ul>
  <div id="objectDetails">
    <div itemprop="description">...</div>
    <div itemprop="foundingDate">...</div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

This web page displays information about one particular organization. Some information about organization should be displayed in a page header, other - in the center of a page. With the help of `itemref` attribute I can split information about organization and put it on two separate divs.

If I test the above HTML with google structured data testing tool - it extracts info about organization correctly - properties from both divs are shown, but it shows validation error on a WebPage object:

> The property `foundingDate` is not recognized by Google for an object of type `WebPage`.

What is the correct way to tell Google that properties that are inside objectDetails div doesn't belong to the outer itemscope (WebPage)? If I add `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"` to objectDetails div - then Google sees two separate organizations on my WebPage.

Comment: Can you maybe work around the problem by keeping the data grouped together according to its logical structure – and use formatting (such as absolute positioning for example) to get it to show up where you want it visually?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

Possible "solutions":

- Don’t use an item on a "container" like `html` or `body`. Use it on an element that doesn’t span the whole content, and use `itemref` if needed.
- Use multiple items and specify the same URI in `itemid` for them. However, it’s not clear [if/when/how Schema.org supports `itemid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632901/1591669), and support from consumers is probably bad.

  (Using [RDFa instead of Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669) would allow this naturally.)
- Add an untyped item (by adding an `itemscope` without `itemtype`) to the element containing all properties you don’t want to add to the original parent item. Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686753/1591669), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32953488/1591669), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683620/1591669).