# Microdata on tables

Tags: html, html-table, microdata

I’m new to Microdata and have a problem with `itemscope` within a `table`.

For example assume I‘ve got a person object and in the table I’m showing Name, Street and City columns.

```
<table>
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <td itemprop="name">Name</td>
    <td itemprop="streetAddress">123 main</td>
    <td itemprop="addressCountry">USA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the `streetAddress` and `addressCountry` are supposed to be children of an `address` property. Yet you can not add a parent `div` to group those within the `table`.

Further it doesn't appear that dot notation works, e.g. `address.streetAddress`.

How would one support this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only rather ugly solutions for this.

You could use the `itemref` attribute for the country, but you’d have to add a dummy untyped `itemscope` so that the `addressCountry` property doesn’t get added to the `Person` item:

```html
<table>
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <td itemprop="name">
      Name
    </td>
    <td itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemref="country">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 main</span>
    </td>
    <td itemscope>
      <span itemprop="addressCountry" id="country">USA</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could use `itemref` for almost anything, so that you don’t have to add a dummy `itemscope`, but the markup gets more complex, and you have to "outsource" the `Person` item:

```html
<meta itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="person-name person-address" />

<!-- can’t have this as descendant of another Microdata item -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td itemprop="name" id="person-name">
      Name
    </td>
    <td itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" id="person-address" itemref="address-country">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 main</span>
    </td>
    <td itemprop="addressCountry" id="address-country">
      USA
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or still have `Person` in the `table` by adding it to the first `td`:

```html
<!-- can’t have this as descendant of another Microdata item -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="person-address">
      <span itemprop="name">Name</span>
    </td>
    <td itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" id="person-address" itemref="address-country">
      <span itemprop="streetAddress">123 main</span>
    </td>
    <td itemprop="addressCountry" id="address-country">
      USA
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The lack of up votes to this question and answer is a bit alarming. I'd expect many site layouts to run into this type of issue, at least if trying to maximize the use of microdata.