# How to use Microdata's 'itemref' to reference similar products that are listed outside of the Product scope?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to use Microdata to define my website using the Schema.org definitions. On an [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage) I am displaying the information about a product. Additionally, I want to [link similar products to the current product](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58261093/) while the related product is being displayed outside of the current product's scope.

I tried to achieve this using the [`itemref`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52570/linking-several-separated-microdata-divs-together/52592#52592) attribute. However, when I review the page on [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) it does not show the related products are part of the `ItemPage` node.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
  <header itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
  </header>

  <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" id="details_10">
    <h2 itemprop="name">Product 10</h2>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <article itemref="details_10" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 20</h3>
    </article>

    <article itemref="details_10" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 30</h3>
    </article>
  </aside>

  <footer itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
  </footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be used the other way around:

- The `itemref` attribute needs to be on the element that represents the item you want to add properties to. This would be the primary product in your case.
- The elements you want to add need the `itemprop` attribute (which you are missing, along with the `isSimilarTo` property), and an `id` that gets referenced by the `itemref` attribute. These would be the similar products in your case.

So, this would give:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">

 <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="details_20 details_30"></article>

 <aside>
   <article id="details_20" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></article>
   <article id="details_30" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></article>
 </aside>

</body>
```

The problem with this markup is that the two `isSimilarTo` properties get added to the `ItemPage`, too (because they are nested under it), which would be incorrect. To avoid this, the best solution would be not to specify the `ItemPage` on the `body` element, but on a `div` or similar.

```html
<body>

 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">

   <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="details_20 details_30"></article>

 </div>

 <aside>
   <article id="details_20" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></article>
   <article id="details_30" itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"></article>
 </aside>

</body>
```

(You could also use `itemref` to avoid having to nest the primary `Product` under the `ItemPage`. This would also allow to specify the `ItemPage` on the `head` element, for example.)

Comment: The problem is that my ItemPage has a header and footer which is why the ItemPage is used at the body. The header and footer are linked using `hasPart`. I have a header on the top, main product details, similar products list and the footer at the end. Not sure how to get around that

Comment: @Junior: You could use `itemref` to add all these items to the `ItemPage` (header, footer, main product: `itemref="header details_10 footer"`). -- There is also [an ugly hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683620/1591669) to avoid that the nested properties for the similar products get added to the `ItemPage`, but I wouldn’t recommend it.