# Microdata parent/child

Tags: html, microdata

I want to add microdata/rich-snippets to my website but the documentation is pretty unclear about some things, suppose i have this CONCEPTUAL code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <div itemprop="name">My Business</div>
    <table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <tr><td itemprop="telephone">0612345678</td></tr>
        <tr><td itemprop="addressCountry">Netherlands</td></tr>
        <-- other postalAdress properties -->
    </table>
</div>
```

That table obviously holds all the contact properties (and is in a table for formatting reasons). The problem is, that table also holds a telephone number. Google microdata tester thinks that the "telephone" property belongs to PostalAddress, it must however belong to the LocalBusiness. How do i fix this?

Comment: Why is there a `itemscope` in your table? Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: @putvande To create an itemscope for PostalAddress?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microdata on tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684960/microdata-on-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Pull the telephone out of the PostalAddress scope:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <span itemprop="name">My Business</span>
    <span itemprop="telephone">0612345678</span>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="addressCountry">Netherlands</span>
        <-- other postalAdress properties -->
    </div>
</div
```

From [schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#microdata_itemscope_itemtype):

> By adding *itemscope*, you are specifying that the HTML contained in the *<div>...</div>* block is about a particular item.

Edit: If you can't change the DOM structure, this is the best I can come up with:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemref="phone">
    <div itemprop="name">My Business</div>
    <table itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <tr itemscope><td itemprop="telephone" id="phone">0612345678</td></tr>
        <tr><td itemprop="addressCountry">Netherlands</td></tr>
        <-- other postalAdress properties -->
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That of course is a possibility but it is evading the problem. I have to redo the whole formatting with this approach. There has got to be a simpler solution because this is a typical namespacing problem.

Comment: @user2501247 I added another example, but I think it is uglier and less-understandable. However, that is the only way I can think of to get that property assigned to your LocalBusiness object. Even though it might seem like additional labor to reorganize your DOM structure, I would avoid the table and write it "better" if you have the opportunity.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if i have two elements who belong in the parent scope, i have invalid HTML-syntax (two tags with same id). I find it kinda ridiculous that the scoping is so badly supported, this seems like a everyday problem.

Comment: @user2501247: The `itemref` attributes takes a space-separated list of ID values. So each property gets its own `id`.

Comment: @unor Nice! The only (last) problem i have, is that PostalAddress shares the `itemprop="telephone"`, i do not want the PostalAddress to have a telephone number at all.

Comment: @user2501247: The `itemscope` attribute on the `tr` element should prevent that the `telephone` property gets added to the `PostalAddress` item.